# Google Analytic Click event not shown in Behavior > Event. Only seen in Real Time > Event

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Hi I have GA (Google Analytic) code to track outbound link on a website.

Here's my code:

```
// this code is under jQuery on click callback
ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'booking',
  eventAction: 'click',
  eventLabel: 'Jungle Book 2016',
  transport: 'beacon'
});
```

It is recorded in Real Time > Event, but nothing listed on Behavior > Event. Do I need to wait for few hours? Or is there something wrong with the code?

Thanks

Comment: It seems there's 24 hour delay before it shows up in Behavior. I'll wait and see

Comment: Yeah, the non real time reports usually aren't entirely up to date. I'd try waiting a few hours to see if that solves it.

Comment: Yep, after waiting for a day, it shows up now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 24 hour delay before the event is registered in Behavior.

You can always check whether your code is working or not via Real Time > Events. If it shows up there, it will be registered in Behavior > Events.